# sql server full text search ranking

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

i'm new to full text search feature. so i need some help.

The question is whether it is possible to set custom ranking in full text search for ms sql server 2008 r2?
What i understand under custom ranking:
i.e. we store books in db. if search term is met in book name of Book1 and in description of Book2 and name has a priority over description, then Book1 should be displayed as the first record.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What answer do you expect ? I could say "Yes" but I'm afraid you might be frustrated... What have you done so far ? Where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: i'm just investigating possible solutions. yes your answer surprised me, 'cause i haven't found information or tutorial how to adjust sql server for custom ranking. if you know such tutorials, please share)

Comment: I found this question today while I was searching... I found this link that can be helpful to anyone with the same problem. [http://developmentnow.com/2006/08/07/weighted-columns-in-sql-server-2005-full-text-search/](http://developmentnow.com/2006/08/07/weighted-columns-in-sql-server-2005-full-text-search/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to roll your own, but no guarantees on performance at scale, so test with realistic data.  The idea is to query the fields individually, add your own custom ranking, and combine the results.

```
 create table DoNotBlindlyRunMe.books 
 (
 id int not null identity primary key,
 Title varchar(100) not null,
 Author varchar(100) not null,
 [Description] varchar(500) not null
 )
 go
 CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [ft_books] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = ON
 GO
 --You need to edit this to match your PK index name!
 CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[books] KEY INDEX [PK__books__3213E83F3D5E1FD2] ON ([ft_books]) WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO)
 GO
 ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[books] ADD ([Author] LANGUAGE [English])
 GO
 ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[books] ADD ([Description] LANGUAGE [English])
 GO
 ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[books] ADD ([Title] LANGUAGE [English])
 GO
 ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[books] ENABLE
 GO

 insert into books (title, author, description)
 values ('The Cat in the Hat',     'Dr. Suess',     'An epic tale of a cat who teaches some valuable lessons.'),
 ('The Little Engine that Could',     'Watty Piper','A small train goes over a mountain.'),
 ('Favorite Nursery Rhymes by Mother Goose', 'Cat Stevens',     'Fairy tales from mother good, including peter piper.')

 --Rank Title highest, then Author, then description
 select [key], min([RANK]) [RANK] from (
      select [key], 100000000+ [RANK] RANK from containstable([books], [Title] , 'cat') union all
      select [key], 200000000+ [RANK] from containstable([books], [Author] , 'cat') union all
      select [key], 300000000+ [RANK] from containstable([books], [Description] , 'cat')
      ) ranked_containstable  GROUP by [key] order by MIN( [RANK] )

 --Or as a TVF
 go
 CREATE FUNCTION  DoNotBlindlyRunMe.RankedBookSearch (@ftQuery nvarchar(500))
 returns table return
 (
 select [key], min([RANK]) [RANK] from (
      select [key], 100000000+ [RANK] RANK from containstable([books], [Title] , @ftQuery) union all
      select [key], 200000000+ [RANK] from containstable([books], [Author] , @ftQuery) union all
      select [key], 300000000+ [RANK] from containstable([books], [Description] , @ftQuery)
      ) ranked_containstable  GROUP by [key]
 )
 go

 select * from dbo.RankedBookSearch(N'cat or stevens or piper')
```